# ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre poner un link CDN y descargar?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, rendimiento, buenas-prácticas

A lo que me refiero es que he visto por ejemplo en Bootstrap puedes ya sea descargarlo y poner un como que mini link en tu editor de texto o puedes solamente poner un link cdn aunque es un poco mas largo, y lo mismo he visto con Jquery, puedes elegir entre poner un link cdn y descargarlo ¿Cúal es la diferencia y cual es mas recomendable usar?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

La diferencia radica en el tiempo de carga de tu sitio.

- Si usas una `CDN` tu sitio no carga con mayor rapidez la diferencia es muy poca.
- Si usas los archivos de tu server (bootstrap descargado) puede tardar un poco la carga

Ahora si llegara a pasar que el link o archivo se haya dañado o movido
CDN:

- No tienes control del archivo por lo tanto tu web dará errores.

Descarga:

- Puedes volver a subirlos o moverlos en su carpeta adecuada.
- Tienes control de esos archivos en el servidor

Comment: `Si usas una CDN tu sitio carga con mayor rapidez` eso no es necesariamente cierto.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo en la afirmación de que el uso de un CDN mejora la velocidad de carga del sitio

Answer (score 16):

Antes que nada no es más recomendable ni lo uno ni lo otro, realmente depende de cada proyecto.

---

La otra respuesta, la cual fue aceptada, explica dos puntos que no son del todo ciertos:

- Usar una CDN **NO** garantiza que el sitio cargue con mayor rapidez. Los servidores de la CDN pueden estar caídos o la conexión hacia ellos muy lenta, entre otras posibles razones.
- Tanto los archivos almacenados en el mismo servidor que la página/sitio web como una CDN, van a tardar **un poco** en cargar, así sea 1ms, pero ambos toman tiempo.

---

Hay una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery) en SO en inglés con respuestas un poco más detalladas, las cuales traduzco a continuación:

Ventajas de usar CDN

- Aumenta el paralelismo (poder hacer solicitudes a varios servidores al tiempo).
- Aumenta la posibilidad que el archivo ya esté en la caché del navegador.
- El tamaño real de descarga del archivo será lo más pequeño posible.
- Reduce el ancho de banda usado por tu servidor.
- Quien visita tu sitio web recibirá una respuesta más cercana (geográficamente hablando).

Cuando no usar una CDN

- Para una intranet cuyo servidor web está en la misma red que los visitantes.
- Cuando desea personalizar dicho recurso (jQuery en este caso).
- Si la aplicación web debe poder funcionar "offline".

Otro punto a tener en cuenta es que puede ser una mejor idea concatenar todos los scripts y ponerlos en un solo archivo (ejemplo scripts.js), que utilizar una CDN, por asuntos de latencia en ciertos dispositivos, aunque al parecer esto ya no es un problema con HTTP2.

Comment: Esto es mas cercano a la realidad que al respuesta aceptada +1