# rapidez entre cdn y descarga de libreria

Tags: javascript, nodejs, librería

### Situación:

Estoy creando un proyecto con una par de compañeros, en el cual utilizamos bastantes librerias, para diferentes cosas.

### Problema:

Ahora mismo estamos centrados en aumentar la rapidez del sitio al maximo, y en cuanto a las libererias tenemos un gran problema, que las opiniones están divididas, entre si es más rapido utilizar cdn o descargar la librería y tenerla en el servidor nuestro.

### Pregunta:

¿Teniendo varias librerias en una página, y teniendo la opcion de utilizar cdn o descargar la librería, cual de las dos últimas es mejor **En cuanto a la velocidad de carga del usuario**?.

PD: Aquí me estoy centrando unica y exclusivamente en la velocidad de carga del usuario, es lo que ncesitamos saber, sé que se podrían comparar desde distintos puntos de vistas, pero el punto de vista que abarco **es la velocidad de carga.**

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cúal es la diferencia entre poner un link cdn y descargar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15432/c%c3%baal-es-la-diferencia-entre-poner-un-link-cdn-y-descargar)

Comment: @BetaM la verdad con ese foro quedé un poco en el aire, pues como tal no me respondió bien la duda, quedé con preguntas, tipo, después de leerlo, sigo sin saber cual elegir.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;TR**: **Sí**, utiliza un CDN que esté cerca de tus clientes potenciales y tenga buena capacidad para manejar las peticiones.

Si bien es cierto que por lo regular los CDN tienden a tener mayor uptime, esto no quiere decir que sean más rápidos en entregar el contenido que pides, sino que estás casi seguro que el contenido va a ser entregado porque el CDN está arriba, pero cuánto tarde en llegar... quién sabe.

En tu caso, creo que las variables más importantes son

- Ubicación del cliente
- Ubicación del CDN
- Velocidad de tráfico del CDN
- Velocidad de descarga del cliente

Entre más cercanos estén el cliente y el CDN, va a ser más rápida la entrega del contenido, y entre mayor tráfico (velocidad y cantidad) pueda manejar el CDN y entre más rápido el cliente pueda pueda descargar el contenido del CDN, la experiencia va a ser mejor.

Ahora, si estás hablando de una aplicación global, quizá lo mejor sea tener una red distribuida como lo hace [netflix](https://about.netflix.com/en/news/how-netflix-works-with-isps-around-the-globe-to-deliver-a-great-viewing-experience), para que cada cliente elija el nodo más cercano y así la experiencia sea la más óptima.

De cualquier forma podrías utilizar un CDN que esté más cerca de tus clientes potenciales y que tenga una muy buena capacidad para el manejo de tráfico. Creo que eso sería lo mejor, así distribuyes la carga de servir el contenido estático al CDN, y dejas que alguien más se encargue de realizar las transacciones o la lógica de la aplicación, esto ayudará a descongestionar las peticiones que reciban los servidores, y así cada servicio podrá responder mejor a las peticiones porque no va a estar saturado.

Pero, antes de invertir en infraestructura o contratar algún servicio, recomendaría que se optimizara la aplicación lo más que se pueda, haciendo uso de [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) con librerías como [require.js](https://requirejs.org/), para evitar cargar toda la aplicación en una sola petición, sino irla cargando paulatinamente según el usuario lo requiera. Eso también ayudará a descongestionar la carga en el CDN, y así podrá ahorrar recursos para procesar más peticiones.

Aún así, no estaría mal hacer pruebas para ver qué es mejor, si utilizar un CDN o servir los archivos por tu cuenta. Por lo que expliqué anteriormente, probablemente el CDN sea el más rápido, pero quién sabe, tal vez te lleves una sorpresa.